# How to add dynamically prefix to routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In session i set default language code for example de. And now i want that in link i have something like this: www.something.com/de/something.

Problem is that i cant access session in routes. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
  $langs = Languages::getLangCode();
    if (in_array($lang, $langs)) {
      Session::put('locale', $lang);
      return redirect::back();
    }
    return;

Route::get('blog/articles', 'StandardUser\UserBlogController@AllArticles');
```

So i need to pass to route as prefix this locale session.

Comment: You should not use language as session just get from uri

Comment: Ok what if i want from app.config? how can i pass value from app.config to route?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a link to your routes with the code of the current language, then you need to create routes group with a dynamic prefix like this:

Example in **Laravel 5.7**:

```
Route::prefix(app()->getLocale())->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return route('index');
    })->name('index');

    Route::get('/post/{id}', function ($id) {
        return route('post', ['id' => $id]);
    })->name('post');
});
```

When you use named routes, URLs to route with current language code will be automatically generated.

Example **links**:

```
http://website.com/en/
http://website.com/en/post/16
```

**Note:** Instead of laravel `app()->getLocale()` method you can use your own `Languages::getLangCode()` method.

If you have more questions about this topic then let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => Languages::getLangCode()
], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'main', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
});
```

Comment: And how can i add dynamically that in link? :)

Comment: and Languages::getLangCode() returns 0=>de 1=>en, i cannot pass that as prefix parmetar i get an error

Comment: 'prefix' => 'de' or 'prefix' => 'en'

Comment: AND add <base href="http://{{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}}/{{Languages::getLangCode()}}">

Comment: Is it possible to pass from app config?